ARIMA, how many lags to select for
I have a series of data with about 700 observations.
To conduct acf and pacf analysis there is a parameter of lags.
How many lags should one use for the acf and pacf?
Is there a percentage that should be used based on the number of observations?
plot_acf(series2, lags=90)
I used the plot acf function but it was hard to identify based on so many lag data points.
